# saleor backend not available under droplet ip from digital ocean

Tags: docker, nginx, portforwarding, saleor

I'd like to deploy my saleor-shop application completely via docker.
So I've built the respective images for saleor backend, storefront & dashboard.

Running the app locally works fine.
Backend is available on localhost:8000/graphql
Storefront runs at localhost:3000
Dashboard runs at localhost:9000

If I'd like to run the app on the droplet IP --> I get issues with running the saleor backend.
As of now trying to access XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:8000 results in "This site can't be reached".
The storefront and dashboard are accessible on XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:3000 and XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:9000 however without any interaction with the backend cause its not available. Thats why the graphql calls are not functioning on the storefront and logging into the dashboard does not work either cause the backend is not available. I think I'm missing something here and would appreciate any help.

[[image: Saleor Storefront][1]]
[image: Saleor Dashboard]

Within my droplet I'm using the following docker-compose.yml file to get my docker containers up:

```html
services:
  api:
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    image: XXX/murukku-shop
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - jaeger
    env_file: common.env
    environment:
      - JAEGER_AGENT_HOST=jaeger
      - STOREFRONT_URL=http://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:3000/
      - DASHBOARD_URL=http://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:9000/

  storefront:
    image: XXX/murukku-storefront
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    restart: unless-stopped

  dashboard:
    image: XXX/murukku-dashboard
    ports:
      - 9000:80
    restart: unless-stopped

  db:
    image: library/postgres:11.1-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    volumes:
      - saleor-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=saleor
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=saleor

  redis:
    image: library/redis:5.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    volumes:
      - saleor-redis:/data

  worker:
    image: XXX/murukku-shop
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    env_file: common.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mailhog
    environment:
      - EMAIL_URL=smtp://mailhog:1025

  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one
    ports:
      - "5775:5775/udp"
      - "6831:6831/udp"
      - "6832:6832/udp"
      - "5778:5778"
      - "16686:16686"
      - "14268:14268"
      - "9411:9411"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - 1025:1025 # smtp server
      - 8025:8025 # web ui. Visit http://localhost:8025/ to check emails
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier

volumes:
  saleor-db:
    driver: local
  saleor-redis:
    driver: local
  saleor-media:

networks:
  saleor-backend-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 3):

I was testing Saleor like you in a docker setup and I've found a solution ! You have to set more env variable, they are all explained on the github page of the [storefront](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-storefront) and the [dashboard](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-dashboard).
Here is my config if you want :

```html
version: '2'

services:
  api:
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    build:
      context: ./saleor
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        STATIC_URL: '/static/'
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - jaeger
    volumes:
      - ./saleor/saleor/:/app/saleor:Z
      - ./saleor/templates/:/app/templates:Z
      - ./saleor/tests/:/app/tests
      # shared volume between worker and api for media
      - saleor-media:/app/media
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file: common.env
    environment:
      # - DEFAULT_CURRENCY=EUR
      #- DEFAULT_COUNTRY=
      - ALLOWED_CLIENT_HOSTS=localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.0.50
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost,192.168.0.50
      - JAEGER_AGENT_HOST=jaeger
      - STOREFRONT_URL=http://192.168.0.50:3000/
      - DASHBOARD_URL=http://192.168.0.50:9000/

  storefront:
    build:
      context: ./saleor-storefront
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./saleor-storefront/:/app:cached
      - /app/node_modules/
    command: npm start -- --host 0.0.0.0
    environment: 
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URI=http://192.168.0.50:8000/graphql/
      - API_URI=http://192.168.0.50:8000/graphql/

  dashboard:
    build:
      context: ./saleor-dashboard
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./saleor-dashboard/:/app:cached
      - /app/node_modules/
    command: npm start -- --host 0.0.0.0
    environment: 
      - API_URI=http://192.168.0.50:8000/graphql/
      - APP_MOUNT_URI=/dashboard/
      - STATIC_URL=http://192.168.0.50:9000/

  db:
    image: library/postgres:11.1-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    volumes:
      - saleor-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=saleor
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=saleor

  redis:
    image: library/redis:5.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    volumes:
      - saleor-redis:/data

  worker:
    build:
      context: ./saleor
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        STATIC_URL: '/static/'
    command: celery -A saleor --app=saleor.celeryconf:app worker --loglevel=info
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    env_file: common.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mailhog
    volumes:
      - ./saleor/saleor/:/app/saleor:Z,cached
      - ./saleor/templates/:/app/templates:Z,cached
      # shared volume between worker and api for media
      - saleor-media:/app/media
    environment:
      - EMAIL_URL=smtp://mailhog:1025

  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one
    ports:
      - "5775:5775/udp"
      - "6831:6831/udp"
      - "6832:6832/udp"
      - "5778:5778"
      - "16686:16686"
      - "14268:14268"
      - "9411:9411"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports: 
      - 1025:1025 # smtp server
      - 8025:8025 # web ui. Visit http://localhost:8025/ to check emails
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier

volumes:
  saleor-db:
    driver: local
  saleor-redis:
    driver: local
  saleor-media:

networks:
  saleor-backend-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

PS : It's my first answer on stackoverflow :D Don't forget to tick me as the answer if I solved your problem ;)